# Why can't I call an function in an anonymous namespace from within another function?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have written this piece of code:

```
namespace {

void SkipWhiteSpace(const char *&s) {
  if (IsWhiteSpace(*s)) {
    s++;
  }
}

bool IsWhiteSpace(char c) {
  return c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n';
}

} // namespace
```

The problem is that the compiler complains that `IsWhiteSpace()` `was not declared in this scope`. But why? Sure, the namespace is anonymous but still the functions lie within the same namespace, aren't they?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps it's because you're defining `IsWhiteSpace` after `SkipWhiteSpace`.

**Edit:**

I successfully compiled the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace
{
    void Function2()
    {
        cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
    }

    void Function1()
    {
        Function2();
    }
}

int main()
{
    Function1();
}
```

Moving `Function1` above `Function2` results in the error you mentioned.  So, yes, it's because `SkipWhiteSpace` has no knowledge of `IsWhiteSpace`.  You can solve this by declaring the functions ahead of time and then defining them normally afterwards, like this:

```
namespace
{
    void Function1();
    void Function2();

    void Function1()
    {
        Function2();
    }

    void Function2()
    {
        cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ouch, ofc, I've hacked too much Java lately ;-).